# mongodump : passing --query argument : error parsing command line options

Tags: mongodb, command-line, command-prompt, database-backups, mongodump

I have a collection sampleColl.

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.sampleColl.find().limit(3);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("64f01e4f58e834c50cdf63c1"), "field" : "2ed2892b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("64f01e4f58e834c50cdf63c2"), "field" : "b48ec1ad" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("64f01e4f58e834c50cdf63c3"), "field" : "1d02b0c2" }
```

When I try to create bson file for the entire collection it works fine.

```
D:\mongodb-database-tools-100.8.0\bin>mongodump --uri="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test" --collection=sampleColl --out=dump --gzip --verbose
2023-08-31T10:40:06.606+0530    dumping up to 1 collections in parallel
2023-08-31T10:40:06.613+0530    writing test.sampleColl to dump\test\sampleColl.bson.gz
2023-08-31T10:40:06.679+0530    done dumping test.sampleColl (10000 documents)
```

Now, if I try to limit the documents using `--query` argument, I run into an error.

```
D:\mongodb-database-tools-100.8.0\bin>mongodump --uri="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test" --collection=sampleColl --query='{"field": {"$gt": "5"}}' --out=dump --gzip --verbose
2023-08-31T10:42:05.872+0530    error parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: provide only one MongoDB connection string. Connection strings must begin with mongodb:// or mongodb+srv:// schemes
2023-08-31T10:42:05.873+0530    try 'mongodump --help' for more information
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trial and errors,

In Windows Command Prompt, escape the `"` with `\` and enclose the query in `"` (double quotes).

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test" --collection=sampleColl --query="{\"field\": {\"$gt\": \"5\"}}" --out=dump --gzip --verbose
```

---

In Windows PowerShell (*PSVersion 5.1.22000.2003*), escape the `"` with `\` and enclose the query in `'` (single quote).

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test" --collection=sampleColl --query='{\"field\": {\"$gt\": \"5\"}}' --out=dump --gzip --verbose
```